# Is c lib a static in c++ program?

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

I have a c lib, algo.lib, which I need to call in my c++ program. I realise that the variables in algo.lib is static, which creates problem for my c++ program, when I call algo.lib multiple times, or use threads to call algo.lib concurrently.

For example, in algo.lib, there is a `int a` which is initiall set to 0. When I call algo.lib the first time, a will be set to 1000. But when I call algo.lib another time, I want the variables in algo.lib to be in the initial state, that is, a = 0 and not a = 1000.

Is it possible to make algo.lib to become object-oriented, so that when I call its function, it is created as an object and is set to its initial state? And after finish running algo.lib, this object is destroyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If you **rewrite** it. If you only have the binary - then you cannot change this behavior. You can solve it by creating a separate executable that will do what you want with it and then exit, and pass the results back to the main program through some IPC. Basically - wrap it with your own implementation that will effectively initialize the library for each separate call.

Comment: rewriting will be very tedious and time-consuming, as this algo.lib belongs to someone else. Thanks for your suggestion, I think I will then compile algo.lib as an excutable instead, and call it in my c++ program, maybe using popen()

Comment: No need. Just write your own API which will initialise the existing library correctly, and/or wrap its functions in your own. Call the new API instead of the old one. `popen()` is overkill for this.

Comment: @spraff, i'm not sure you're right. The OP has a global variable in the library, that gets changed on each call, and apparently it cannot be reset once loaded, and is inaccessible from outside. If that's the case - just wrapping the API's won't help.